# sort number and number with letters(suffix) in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, sorting

I would like to sort the values

```
    [101,102,103,101a,101b,104,103a,102a] as [101,101a,101b,102,102a,103,103a,104].
```

Is it possible with JavaScript default functions(if any) or using Regex. I was struct with this simple one for whole day.

Any suggestions please?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: first of all it should be an array strings like `['101',...,'101a']`. You can use `.sort()` on that array

Comment: aha, I missed it . Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2):

`array.sort()` will do it for you!

[jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ssmz4w0p/1/)

Comment: It might be worth noting that it would require the number part to always be the same length (e.g. 3 digits), depending on requirements of course

Comment: Yup, it would depend on the sorting order which OP wants :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that these are supposed to be strings (you're missing quotes in your post), then the default sort (ie, with `['101', '102', '101b', '101a'].sort()`) should work.

It sorts strings in [lexicographical order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) (aka dictionary order).

Of course, if you have `['10', '20', '100']`, it will fail. Your options are to prefix things with zeros (ie, `['010', '020', '100']`) or to provide a custom comparator. Eg, if it's always a number then a letter:

```
['100b', '100a', '10', '20'].sort(function(item1, item2) {
    var firstInt = parseInt(item1, 10);
    var secondInt = parseInt(item2, 10);
    if(firstInt != secondInt) return firstInt - secondInt;
    else return item1.charCodeAt(item1.length - 1) - item2.charCodeAt(item2.length - 1);
});
```

This assumes that there's only a single trailing character. It takes advantage of the fact that if the strings are the same number (with no character), then the else statement will trivially return 0. It will not work on empty strings.